# Intermittent ConnectionRefusedError when acquiring lock on macOS

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, locking, shared-memory

The code below comes from some work where I was trying to develop robust strategies for working with multiprocessing and shared memory.

When the RANGE value is relatively low (say 25) this program runs consistently without error. However, if I increase to ~100 it fails intermittently with a ConnectionRefusedError (Errno 61) when trying to acquire the lock.

Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and would appreciate ideas.

Here's the code (sorry it's so long but it's the minimum required to reproduce the problem).

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from multiprocessing import Manager
from struct import unpack_from, pack_into
from itertools import repeat

FMT = '@I'
RANGE = 100
SHM = '_shm'


class ShmWm(SharedMemory):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        super().close()

    def unlink(self):
        super().unlink()


def process(lock):
    try:
        locked = False
        with lock:
            locked = True
            with ShmWm(SHM) as shared:
                v, = unpack_from(FMT, shared.buf)
                pack_into(FMT, shared.buf, 0, v+1)
    except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
        if not locked:
            print('Failed to acquire lock', e)
        raise


def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        lock = manager.Lock()
        try:
            with ShmWm(SHM, True, 4) as shared:
                try:
                    pack_into(FMT, shared.buf, 0, 0)
                    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                        executor.map(process, repeat(lock, RANGE))
                    v, = unpack_from(FMT, shared.buf)
                    assert v == RANGE
                    print('All OK')
                finally:
                    shared.unlink()
        except AssertionError:
            print(f'{v=} but was expected to be {RANGE}')
        except Exception as e:
            print('main:', e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Platform:**

Python 3.10.6, macOS 12.5.1, 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W, 32 GB 2666 MHz DDR4

**Output:**

```
Failed to acquire lock [Errno 61] Connection refused
Process SpawnProcess-15:
Failed to acquire lock [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 942, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 792, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 846, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 507, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 635, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Failed to acquire lock [Errno 61] Connection refused
Process SpawnProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 942, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 792, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 846, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 507, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 635, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
v=65 but was expected to be 100
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback, or is it all there is?

Comment: After testing this for a while (with `RANGE` as 100,000, 100 times), I did not encounter this error. A `ConnectionRefusedError` seems to suggest that requests to the manager were sent from proxies before it spawned a server (which should be impossible), or that the server died some time after starting (could happen if no pointers remain to proxies within manager). Have you tried checking the multiprocessing logs?

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal Thank you for reviewing this. Can you confirm that you tested this on macOS? I have added the full output. Note the first line of output. I have no idea how/where to check multiprocessing logs. Perhaps you can help with that

Comment: Logging is pretty simple, just add `logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr() ; logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to the start of your script (outside main). The traceback does suggest that you do lose connection to the manager process, using the logs here would be helpful to confirm that.

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal I'm seeing BrokenPipeError

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal It appears to be a problem with ProcessPoolExecutor. If I use a regular Pool the problem does not arise even with RANGE=1000

Comment: Good to see you have found a workaround, but for logging, you can refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#logging) section in the documentation. As to why this is happening, I am not sure, more so because I was not able to reproduce this issue. Looking over the source code, there does seem to be a difference in using a regular pool where the worker processes are started as daemon, which is not the case with `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which might be relevant here. Can you reproduce this on another device? There isn't much that can be done without the logs here